# Presenting a SKSpritenode from different class ("addChild")

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a Class for my Sprite and I'm trying to addChild from that class. The problem is it renders it and doesn't crash - I just can't see the image. I know the images position is right because created and added the child from the gameScene class and it worked and loaded.

- I'm thinking this isn't working because its not subclass of SKscene that's why I added the main node from gameScene but didn't solve the problem.
- I set up a "mainNode" node
- keys is just the name of the sprite and its the class name
- I know the image is being rendered its just not visible for some reason.

I know this because if I add no image name not "key_green" and change it to nothing. I get an console msg saying it can't find that image.

> gameScene.m

```
#import "GameScene.h"
#import "Keys.h"

@implementation GameScene

@synthesize mainNode;


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   mainNode = [SKNode node];

   [self addChild:mainNode];


   Keys * KeysOBJ =[[Keys alloc] init];
   [KeysOBJ initKeys];


}
```

> keys.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface Keys : SKSpriteNode{

SKSpriteNode * key1;

}


@property SKNode* mainNode;



-(void)initKeys;
-(void)loadKeys;
```

> keys.m

```
#import "Keys.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation Keys{


 }
 @synthesize mainNode;




  -(void)initKeys{


   key1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"key_red"];
   key1.position = CGPointMake((self.frame.size.width)-  (self.frame.size.width)+350, (self.frame.size.height)-(self.frame.size.height)+50);


   [mainNode addChild:key1];

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mainNode is nil in your Keys because you never set it before you call initKeys. This in theory will get it working.

```
Keys * KeysOBJ =[[Keys alloc] init];
KeysOBJ.mainNode = mainNode;

[KeysOBJ initKeys];
```

Also consider this

```
key1.position = CGPointMake((self.frame.size.width)-  (self.frame.size.width)+350, (self.frame.size.height)-(self.frame.size.height)+50);
```

`self` doesn't have a size because you just called init and never supplied a texture or a size. Meaning your sprite location will likely be 350,50.

With that being said you are over complicating it. Your Keys shouldn't be a subclass of SKSpriteNode if you are never going to set a texture to it. It should be a SKNode.

Hopefully that makes some sense and gets you pointed back in the right direction.